# How to copy a specific range between two mmap?

Tags: python, slice, mmap

How is it possible to only copy a specific part of one mmap into another via slices?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import mmap

a = mmap.mmap(-1, 5)
b = mmap.mmap(-1, 5)

a[0:] = b'12345'
b[0:] = b'67890'

a[2:6] = b[0:4]

print(a[:])
```

Is there a way to copy such a range via slices? If this is not possible, what other solutions exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mush be getting below error:

> IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size

change `a[2:6] = b[0:4]` to

```
a[1:5] = b[0:4]
```

output:

```
b'16789' # print(a[:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it isn't really clear what you are expecting, the above code will not work because you are using an invalid range. Calling `a[2:6]` will return a slice of size three, (i.e. it will return `a[2:5]` since `a[6]` doesn't actually exist) resulting in an error `IndexError: mmap slice assignment is wrong size`

Try running this with `a[1:5] = b[0:4]`. This yields:

```
print(a[:])
b'16789'
```